# Google Sheets Countif range is greater than range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So, quite simply I am trying to count if B4>A4 and B5>A5... ect.

I could do something like this:

```
=COUNTIF(B4,">"&A4)+COUNTIF(B5,">"&A5)+...
```

There's got to be a better way using ranges. (Sorry if that formula doesn't actually work)

The formula I have right now:

```
=COUNTIF(B$4:B30,">"&A$4:A30)
```

(this is in cell B31)

I've tried many different ways of doing this, but none of them have worked so far. This includes:

```
-using COUNTIFS
-Having the range include A ("A$4:B30")
-Having the criteria contain both sides (B$4:B30&">"&A$4:A30)
-Not using quotes
-I tried using ARRAYFORMULA and that gave me a mess. But I'm also not that great with ARRAYFORMULA so I might be doing something wrong.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(N(B4:B30>A4:A30)))
```

[image]

Comment: So this worked, can you explain how this works? I'm not familiar with the INDEX function.

Comment: INDEX is same as ArrayFormula - its just shorter to type. works like this: first range is compared to 2nd range. the output of that is TRUE/FALSE that is converted to 1/0 with N() and then SUM() will "count" all ones